# Laravel 5 - vendor:publish does not overwrite old files

Tags: laravel-5

Hi I have a problem where Laravel 5's vendor:publish command does not override old package assets. Does anyone know if this is the correct behaviour or do I have to somehow delete the old previous version before I can publish?

regards

Comment: never mind, didn't see the `--force` option

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using the `--force` flag.

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --force
```

Comment: can i do it inside the provider somehow? the reason i ask is that if i run --force via bash files it throws an error (no error via command line)